# JSDoc nested types not showing on VSCode

Tags: javascript, comments, documentation, jsdoc, type-definition

I have this code:

typedefs.js

```js
/**
 * A UUID.
 * Example: 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655540000
 *
 * @typedef {string} uuid
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Notification
 *
 * @property {uuid} id - The notification ID.
 */
```

code.js

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import('../typedefs').Notification} Notification
 */

/**
 * @returns {Notification} - An array of notifications.
 */
export const getNotification = () => {
};
```

When I hover on `{Notification}` it shows:
[image]
But I expected it to show `uuid` instead of `string`.